# Regex - Expressão para pegar campos limitados

Tags: regex

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
"Let's put some bits in your home"
```

Utilizando expressão regular, como eu poderia pegar somente as informações do `bits` pra frente, ficando:

```
bits in your home
```

Ou seja, as demais palavras são descartadas.

Alguém já viu algum caso assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende muito das variações que a `String` de entrada pode ter, e de quais caracteres você quer pegar.

O caso mais simples é:

```
(bits.*)
```

Que pega `bits` + tudo que tiver depois.

Só que `.*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caracter".

Se você não quiser alguns tipos de caracter, ou só quiser determinados tipos (como letras, números ou espaços), ou qualquer outra regra, pode restringir mais usando algo como o sugerido pela [resposta do Israel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/299066/112052).

Por exemplo:

```
(bits[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)
```

`[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` vai pegar somente letras, números ou espaço (zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer um destes caracteres). Mude a expressão de acordo com o que você precisar.

---

Por padrão, o `.` [não considera as quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (`\n` e `\r`), embora algumas linguagens/APIs permitem que você configure isso ([exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11644132)). Não sei se isso se aplica ao seu caso (já que não foi especificado), mas é um ponto de atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer pegar sempre após a palavra 'bits', pode utilizar essa expressão simples:

`(bits[^\n]*)`

Ela captura tudo após (e incluindo) a palavra 'bits' até achar uma quebra de linha.

[Veja este exemplo funcionando](https://regexr.com/3pgag)